# Push view controller with custom page curl animation

Tags: iphone

I want page curl like animation when I push another view.  I don't need the default one.
Can I push view with custom animation?  I have image sequence.
How can we do that? Help me, please!

Comment: Sorry bt didnt get you,can you help please

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using QuartzCore framwork.

first, #import  and before push view controller add this code.
Hope you are OK!

```
    YourViewController *viewControlle = [[YourViewController alloc] init];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1.0;
    transition.type = @"pageUnCurl";
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    transition.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer 
     addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

    [self.navigationController 
     pushViewController:viewControlle animated:NO];
```

Comment: I think, there are not listed in xcode . So ultimately doesn't want to   use these types. These are highly battery drainage.